# flutter - type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of type 'String'
when I retrieved data from sqflite, and I want to add it to widget

```
Future<List> getSpecificForm({String tableName, formId}) async { 
  final db = await database; 
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await db.rawQuery( 'SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id=? ORDER BY id DESC', [formId]); 
  return result; 
}
```

Comment: can you provide a source code?

Comment: Future<List> getSpecificForm({String tableName, formId}) async {
    final db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await db.rawQuery(
        'SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id=?   ORDER BY id DESC', [formId]);

    return result;
  }

Comment: "formId" is a String? can you provide the code which call getSpecificForm. maybe you have a cast when you treat response of getSpecificForm method

Comment: Yes, "formId" is a String.
I call the function like this code:
 await DBHelper.db.getSpecificForm(
                            tableName: DynamicJsonSchemaFormTable.tableName,
                            formId: '12')

Comment: Sorry, i have test your code inside my application, it works. I don't understand your error. your id in table is a string or other type? prefer add required before tableName and formId when you use optional parameters

Comment: actually it returns data, but the problem is that, when I want to use the returned data as map for example, first element in the list it does not work as Map<String, dynamic>, it is a rawquery.

Comment: I mean, when  I print the runtimeType for first element of returned list the runtimeType  is QueryRow.  why is not a Map<String, dynamic>,?

Comment: Thank you very much @Thetyne for your help.
I found the sol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I changed the function like this:

```
Future<List> getSpecificForm({String tableName, formId}) async {
    final db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result =  await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id=?', [formId]);

    return List<Map<String, dynamic>>.generate(
        result.length, (index) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(result[index]),
        growable: true
    );
}
```

and the return type of elements of the returned list is `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`